# How to add a partial entry into relational DB with entity core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relational-database

**The Program:**
My program reads from a file and then stores the values in a relational db.

**The Models**
ClientDetails, ClientVehicle, ClientOrder

**The Relationship:**

- 1 client can have many vehicles
- 1 vehicle can have many orders

**The Problem:**
The program does not support duplicate data.

**The Struggle**
I need to be able to not add a client if the client already exists but still have the client linked to the vehicle when storing the vehicle (Entity core handles the foreign keys for me, but when simply skipping half the record I get foreign key constraints). This same process needs to work if a vehicle with the same registration plate gets added.

**The Struggle Continues**
To top off this problem I also need to be able to do these checks on the file itself as I only save the context changes into the db at the end of the whole process so if the file contains 2 records with the same user but different vehicles (1 client can have many vehicles) then I need to only add the user once.

**The Hope**
I am hoping that somebody can tell me if there is a built in entity core method that can sort this out for me. I have seen some entity framework things that I estimate would fix this but I can't find the entity core equivalent. for example _context.AddIfNotExists. Or something along the lines of _context.AddOrUpdate(entity, k = k.id = record[0]). If a post like this already exist please direct me as I could not find it myself.

**NOTE**
When a duplicate client is found the rest of the entry should still happen as this is an "order", its only the client that needs to be skipped (or vehicle in the event of the same registration plate).

**The Code Snippet In Question**

```
public void LoadCsv(string path)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
        _now = DateTime.Now;
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (count > 0)
            {
                var record = line.Split('|').ToList();

                var entityClientDetails = AddClientDetails(record, _now);
                var entityClientVehicle = AddClientVehicle(record, _now);
                var entityClientOrder = AddClientOrder(record, _now);
                entityClientDetails.ClientVehicles.Add(entityClientVehicle);
                entityClientVehicle.ClientOrders.Add(entityClientOrder);
                _context.Add(entityClientDetails);
            }
            count++;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: post your model. we dont know which are main class or sub class.

Comment: My apologies if I don't understand but isn't that answered by the relationship? ClientDetails is the main model, ClientVehicle is dependent on ClientDetails and ClientOrder is dependent on ClientVehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public void LoadCsv(string path)
    {
        var clients = _context.ClientDetails.AsQueryable();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
        _now = DateTime.Now;
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (count > 0)
            {
                var record = line.Split('|').ToList();

                var entityClientDetails = AddClientDetails(record, _now);
                var entityClientVehicle = AddClientVehicle(record, _now);
                var entityClientOrder = AddClientOrder(record, _now);

                var clientExist = clients.Where(x => x.RegistrationPlate == entityClientDetails.RegistrationPlate).FirstOrDefault();
                entityClientVehicle.ClientOrders.Add(entityClientOrder);

                if (clientExist != null)
                {
                      entityClientVehicle.ClientDetailID = clientExist.Id;
                      _context.Add(entityClientVehicle);
                }
                else
                {
               entityClientDetails.ClientVehicles.Add(entityClientVehicle);
                      _context.Add(entityClientDetails);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Asherguru, this works! I will update this as the answer in a second. Just duplicating the logic for a difference instance. Thanks man/wham :)

Comment: I replicated it for a few nested occasions and adjusted where needed and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot, been struggling on this one for a while.